# $ \ \lim_{x\to ∞ }\frac{π(x)} { x^δ} $

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $\ π(x)$ denote the prime counting function , i.e. the number of primes not exceeding $x$
Then does $$ \ \lim_{x\to ∞ }\frac{π(x)} { x^δ} $$ exist for all real $δ$ $∈ ( 0 , 1 )$

Comment: What does $\pi\left(x\right)$ mean?

Answer (score 2):

No, because the prime number theorem states that $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{\log{x}}$.  Since $\log{x} \lt x^\delta$ for any $\delta \gt 0$ and sufficiently large $x$, the limit diverges.

Comment: I know the asymptotic nature of $π(x)$ but can not really seem to get the proof for divergence of the said limit , can you please give it more formally

Comment: It follows algebraically from PNT and $\log{x} \lt x^\delta$ for all sufficiently large $x$ and $\delta \gt 0$, which I won't show, but you should be able to find references for the fact on this site.